# What are Android RemoteViews and RemoteView fectory class

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android world.
Can anyone please explain the basic meaning of RemoteViews and RemoteViewsFectory class in android in very basic language.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation:

> [`RemoteViews` is] a class that describes a view hierarchy that can be displayed in another process. The hierarchy is inflated from a layout resource file, and this class provides some basic operations for modifying the content of the inflated hierarchy.

So, we use this in situations where an app wants to define a UI, but it is some other process that will actually display the UI.

The two most common use cases are [app widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) and custom [notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

A `RemoteViewsFactory` supplements a `RemoteViews` that contains a `ListView` or `StackView`. It serves the same role as does a `ListAdapter`, creating the individual rows for the `ListView`, for example.